# How to get gdb to break on "CHKP: Bounds check error" from icc `-check-pointers=write`

Tags: c++, gdb, icc

The Intel **icc** compiler has a run-time check feature `-check-pointers=write` that does some sort of magic to check if a pointer writes beyond data it is supposed to. When I run this on my code, I get hundreds of these errors rolling by in **gdb**. I would like to have **gdb** break on the first instance of this error, but it is not implemented as an exception or signal, so `catch throw` or `catch signal` doesn't work, and I have no idea if there is a function name associated with this feature.

Is there any way to have the debugger "break" when the run-time checker hits it?

Answer (score 1):

The `-check-pointers` feature installs code from `libchkp.so` and all of the functions have the `chkp` prefix in them. A quick search of the functions in gdb using `info functions chkp` showed that the traceback function is called "chkp_print_traceback", so this will install a break point when the traceback happens:

```
break chkp_print_traceback
```

and now it stops!

```
[New Thread 0x7fffce34c700 (LWP 41385)]
[New Thread 0x7fffceb4d700 (LWP 41384)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd034e700 (LWP 41383)]
CHKP: Bounds check error ptr=0x7ffe24685870 sz=4 lb=0x7ffe24685860 ub=0x7ffe2468586f loc=0xb170b0
[New Thread 0x7ffec47fc700 (LWP 41621)]
[New Thread 0x7ffe29fff700 (LWP 41622)]
[New Thread 0x7ffed47fe700 (LWP 41603)]
[New Thread 0x7ffecc7fe700 (LWP 41605)]
[New Thread 0x7ffef07f8700 (LWP 41598)]
[New Thread 0x7fff147f8700 (LWP 41597)]
[New Thread 0x7fff387f8700 (LWP 41595)]
[New Thread 0x7fff687f8700 (LWP 41594)]
[New Thread 0x7fff707f8700 (LWP 41590)]
[New Thread 0x7fff907f8700 (LWP 41589)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb45ec700 (LWP 41587)]
[New Thread 0x7ffec4ffd700 (LWP 41577)]
[New Thread 0x7ffec57fe700 (LWP 41442)]
[New Thread 0x7ffec7fff700 (LWP 41441)]
[New Thread 0x7ffecefff700 (LWP 41440)]
[New Thread 0x7ffed5fff700 (LWP 41439)]
[New Thread 0x7ffef0ff9700 (LWP 41438)]
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffec47fc700 (LWP 41621)]

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ffff5f32d74 in chkp_print_traceback () from /opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/lib/intel64/libchkp.so
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff5f32d74 in chkp_print_traceback () from /opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/lib/intel64/libchkp.so
#1  0x00007ffff5f31706 in __chkp_check_bounds () from /opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/lib/intel64/libchkp.so
#2  0x0000000000b170b0 in redacted
```